# How to save and load a giant hash-table to-n-fro from disk?

Tags: c, search, data-structures, hash, indexing

I am trying to write a search-engine for a large collection, for learning purposes. I started with my own intuitions. Then I researched and am finally arriving at a working model.

I am constructing a giant hash-table to hold all the terms in my collection. It is very expensive to construct this from the collection. Once I have computed the table I want to save this to disk, so that whenever I want to access this hash-table in my program latter, I can load it again from disk.

**Is there any standard way of doing it or do I have to invent my own file-format and hacks to do this?**

**Note**: The has-table is only for storing all term occurrences, I am planning to store the main ranking data in a postings file and have its pointer set in corresponding term of hash-table.

I am working in C.

Comment: Store it as a list of key-value pairs? Not sure if that's what you're looking for. But, generally computing the hash is cheap, so it's reasonable to reconstruct it from such a list.

Comment: Databases and other disk-oriented storages use b+ trees.

Comment: @FatalError The has-table is only for storing all term occurrences, I am planning to store the main ranking data in a postings file and have its pointer set in corresponding term in hash-table.

Comment: What OS do you use? Did you try `mmap`?

Comment: @Eddy_Em I am on a 32-bit Ubuntu. Doesn't mmap have the limitation of maximum addressable space of 4GB? I have a related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388408/how-should-i-store-address-of-posting-file-for-a-term-t-in-index I would like to talk to you if you have time and know a lot more about mmap() and saving DS to disks

Comment: @Sravan, yes, if you want to use large addressing on 32bit, you should directly tell gcc that off_t is 64bit. Better use 64bit system if you work with large arrays of data.

Comment: `mmap` is something like reading data by parts from disk to memory buffer, but it works transparently, so you don't need to take care about right bufferisation and memory rearrangement.

Answer (score 1):

[BDB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/programmer_reference/index.html) is a library for efficiently managing flat-file databases.  In particular a hash table format is supported.  B-Trees are also available, in case ordered access is required.

Comment: Thanks @phs. I have found [tpl](http://troydhanson.github.com/tpl/) and [eet](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/efl/eet&l=en) and now BDB. I am trying to figure out which one is best in a search-engine indexing scenario.

Comment: Incidentally, I maintain a search engine professionally (http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/); we use B-Tree BDBs extensively.

Comment: I am lucky to find you! I have some more questions on search-engine topic as I am currently working on it. Could you come to this chat-room http://groups.gaglers.com/r/ENeO/ if you have little time. I won't eat much of your time!

Comment: Thanks phs! The chat really helped me.

Using BDB would destroy my purpose of implementing search-engine on my own. And also I am trying to have everything light in C, without having a DB connection & stuff. 
Thanks a lot for the help!